# Show/ Hide select field when other select option is chosen in WP user fields

Tags: jquery, wordpress, select

I'm trying to add some custom user fields to the WP user profile page, but I can't seem to get it working. I want to add a dropdown for facility. Depending on which facility is chosen, I'd like to show another dropdown for locations in that facility.

My problem is that all the locations dropdowns are always shown regardless of which facility is selected.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#user_facility').change(function() {
      if ( this.value == 'option1') {
        $('#select1').show();
      } else {
          $('#select1').hide();
      }

      if ( this.value == 'option2') {
        $('#select2').show();
      } else {
          $('#select2').hide();
      }
    });
});
</script>

<select name="user_facility" id="user_facility">
    <option value="option1" <?php selected( 'option1', get_the_author_meta( 'user_facility', $user->ID ) ); ?>> option1</option>
    <option value="option2" <?php selected( 'option2', get_the_author_meta( 'user_facility', $user->ID ) ); ?>> option2</option>
</select>

<select name="select1" id="select1">
   ...some options
</select>

<select name="select2" id="select2">
   ...some options
</select>
```

If anyone can help point me in the right direction, it would be, as always, greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check selected option value via `$(this).val()` not `this.value`. Anyways just change your codes with follows -

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('#user_facility').change(function() {
          if ( $(this).val() == 'option1') {
            $('#select1').show();
          } else {
              $('#select1').hide();
          }

          if ( $(this).val() == 'option2') {
            $('#select2').show();
          } else {
              $('#select2').hide();
          }
        }).change();
    });
    </script>

    <select name="user_facility" id="user_facility">
        <option value="option1" <?php selected( 'option1', get_the_author_meta( 'user_facility', $user->ID ) ); ?>> option1</option>
        <option value="option2" <?php selected( 'option2', get_the_author_meta( 'user_facility', $user->ID ) ); ?>> option2</option>
    </select>

    <select name="select1" id="select1" style="display: none;">
       ...some options
    </select>

    <select name="select2" id="select2" style="display: none;">
       ...some options
    </select>
```

Comment: thanks @itzmekhokan, unfortunately there's no change. All select options are still being shown regardless of which option is selected in #user_facility

Comment: The above scripts is tested and working properly. And all the dependent select boxes are hidden via `display: none`. Can you double check with clear caches.

Comment: I'm getting an error with the above code for this line: `jQuery(document).ready(function($){` Can't find variable: jQuery

Comment: I'm linking it now, though I was pretty sure it was part of WP core.

Comment: Oh geez, that was the issue. Thanks! Accepted!

Comment: Make sure you have loaded jQuery first. Or else if your previous scripts is workable on ready state then you can replaced the line with your own `$(document).ready(function(){`